# How to place advertisement after first sentence of wordpress post?

Tags: wordpress, code-injection, ads

I wonder what technique to use to place ad after first or maybe second sentence of WP post.

Actually there can be more variations and troubles (HTML tags used in post itself, code inserted by other plugins executed before our one)

I'm not sure if its safe to simply use PHP explode function (by dot at the end of the sentences)

Or maybe there is already plugin created for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty answer that works surprisingly well.

```
<?php
    $ad       = '<b>!!!ADVERTISEMENT!!!</b>';
    $content = get_the_content();
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

    //Matches a word with a space before it and a period after it.
    $array        = preg_split('/\s(\w+){1}\.(?!\w)/', $content, 2, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $end              = array_pop($array);
    $delimiterMatch  = array_pop($array);
    $delimiterMatch .= '. ';//the period disappeared and im too lazy to find out why.
    $beginning    = array_pop($array);

    echo $beginning . $delimiterMatch . $ad . $end;

?>
```

Feel free to mess around with the regular expression to get the split u want.